# Foreign language scenes in Indiana Jones and the Dial of Destiny

Tags: dialogue, indiana-jones, subtitles, indiana-jones-and-dial-of-destiny

I am currently abroad and wondering if there are foreign language scenes in *Indiana Jones and the Dial of Destiny*, which I will not be able to understand due to subtitles being in a language I don't know.

Comment: What language will you be watching the film in?

Comment: I am French, and saw the movie in Japan in English with Japanese subtitles. I had no comprehension problems.